# Does Quartz jdbc store save job execution history?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

The quartz has [LoggingJobHistoryPlugin](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/previous_versions/2.1.0/org/quartz/plugins/history/LoggingJobHistoryPlugin.html) and also has a [jdbc JobStore](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX). So does the jdbc job store save all (not last only) execution history? Also can `LoggingJobHistoryPlugin` store history in database?

Answer (score 3):

The quick answer is no, you have to create your own log insertion code to the database via the listeners.

It would've been a cool feature.